# Updating the number of radiobuttons and their labels in android quiz

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Hey I'm writing a quiz application for android.  Some of the questions asked require just true or false, and some you need to pick from 4 possible options.  I've implemented an intereface with 4 radiobuttons and got that to work fine.

I was just wondering what the best way would be to adjust the number of radiobuttons depending on the question type?  I've added in an extra field in my question object to state the number of possible answer choices, but i'm unsure how to use this in my program.  Any pointers would be appreciated!

At the moment i'm using a textswitcher to update the question asked when I click next and was wondering whether I could use an imageswitcher to make the desired change with the radiobuttons?

ADDITIONALLY - I was thinking about how I could update the labels on the radiobuttons to the possible choices instead of simply A, B, C etc. just to make it look nicer.

Comment: I don't know a dang thing about Android programming, but it sounds like you need data binding. Bind the labels of the controls to each possible field of data, dynamically create extra controls (more radio buttons) to let you pick each answer. Hopefully this sets you off in the right direction of research...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these 2

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29